# Basic puppet configuration doesn't work

Tags: puppet, fedora

I forgot to put node command in site.pp, something like this:

```
class emacs {
    package {
emacs:
        ensure => installed
    }
}

node default {
        include emacs
}
```

**Original question**:

I installed puppetd and puppetmaster on my workstation. I'm running Fedora14, puppetd, puppetmaster version 0.25.5. When I run puppetmaster and puppet I get this in /var/log/messages:

```
Apr 20 08:51:31 localhost puppetmasterd[4734]: Reopening log files
Apr 20 08:51:31 localhost puppetmasterd[4734]: Starting Puppet server version 0.25.5
Apr 20 08:51:43 localhost puppetd[4768]: Reopening log files
Apr 20 08:51:43 localhost puppetd[4768]: Starting Puppet client version 0.25.5
Apr 20 08:51:44 localhost puppetmasterd[4734]: Compiled catalog for localhost.localdomain in 0.00 seconds
Apr 20 08:51:44 localhost puppetd[4768]: Finished catalog run in 0.09 seconds
```

My /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp is like this:

```
class emacs {
    package {
emacs:
        ensure => installed
    }
}

class mc {
    package {
mc:
        ensure => purged
    }
}
```

I put just simple configuration, just to see if this is working.

/etc/puppet/puppet.conf is:

```
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
[puppetd]
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    report = true
```

/etc/sysconfig/puppet have:

```
PUPPET_SERVER=localhost.localdomain
```

And /etc/sysconfig/puppetmaster have:

```
PUPPETMASTER_MANIFEST=/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

I don't understand why puppet isn't installing packages that I putted in configuration. Did I missed something?

Comment: Please feel free to add your answer using the **Post your answer** button below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your client resolve the fqdn correctly? run dig puppetmaster.domainname.com, and what result do you get?

also, did you configure the clients certificate on the puppetmaster?

Comment: I'm using /etc/hosts and localhost.localdomain for PUPPET_SERVER, and it resolves fine, not with dig but ping works. And certifications are not a problem, if you look at /var/log/messages you will see it doesn't complain about it. I had a problem when I used only localhost for PUPPET_SERVER, but now it works with FQDN.

Comment: If it now works, then accept - or if I didn't understand, what's still wrong?